# create .so by linking to combination of other .so and .a files

Tags: c, linux, gcc, shared-libraries

I need to create a **.so** by linking it to other opensource libraries (some available as **.so** and some as **.a**)

Is it possible to create a **.so** by linking it with combination of .so and .a

E.g. Say I'm trying to create `libfinal.so` by linking it with `liba.so`, `libb.a`

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libfinal.so -Wl,--no-undefined -la -lb
```

The above command is trying to find **libb.so** which is not available. Any solution?

**UPDATE**: The problem seems to be libb.a is compiled with out -fPIC option. 
Error --> relocation R_MIPS_26 against `libipt_DNAT_init' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Comment: IIRC object files (and archives thereof) must be listed without option. I.e try : `gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libfinal.so -Wl,--no-undefined -la b`

Comment: Explicitly use the full path and file name?

Comment: Adding full path results in the following error. --> could not read symbols: Bad value

Comment: @AnupPatil what about my modification above ?

Comment: With `-L.` added, compilation line is more or less correct. If linker cannot read `libb`, then most likely libb is broken or compiled for different platform.

Comment: @Quentin adding -L. b or b  instead of adding -lb shows file b not found error :(

Comment: @AnupPatil because I forgot half of it :D `gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libfinal.so -Wl,--no-undefined -la libb.a` ought to work, as stated in Shubhangi's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Below is command syntax to link object files , archives and libraries.

```
gcc -o <output file> -l<library> objectfiles|archives
```

E.g. Linking libc.so.6, Ex.o and binary1.a to generate MyEx.so

```
gcc -o MyEx.so -lc Ex.o binary1.a
```

*Note : An archive (.a) is nothing but a single file holding a collection of other files*